# How to extract .class files from nested Jar?

Tags: java, jar, nested

I have a Jar file named "**OuterJar.jar**" that contains another jar named "**InnerJar.jar**" this InnerJar contains 2 files named "**Test1.class**" & "**Test2.class**".Now i want to extract these two files. I have tried some piece of code but it doesn't work.

```
class NestedJarExtractFactory{

  public void nestedJarExtractor(String path){

    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(path);


     Enumeration entries = jarFile.entries();

          while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

           JarEntry  _entryName = (JarEntry) entries.nextElement();

                      if(temp_FileName.endsWith(".jar")){

        JarInputStream innerJarFileInputStream=new JarInputStream(jarFile.getInputStream(jarFile.getEntry(temp_FileName)));
        System.out.println("Name of InnerJar Class Files::"+innerJarFileInputStream.getNextEntry());
       JarEntry innerJarEntryFileName=innerJarFileInputStream.getNextJarEntry();
///////////Now hear I need some way to get the Input stream of this class file.After getting inputStream i just get that class obj through 
           JavaClass clazz = new ClassParser(InputStreamOfFile,"" ).parse();

}

///// I use the syntax 
  JavaClass clazz = new ClassParser(jarFile.getInputStream(innerJarEntryFileName),"" ).parse();
```

**But the problem is that the "jarFile" obj is the obj of OuterJar File so when trying to get the inputStream of a file that exists in the InnerJar is not possible.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a second `JarInputStream` to process the inner entries.
This does what you want:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("OuterJar.jar");
JarInputStream jin = new JarInputStream(fin);
ZipEntry ze = null;
while ((ze = jin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (ze.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
        JarInputStream jin2 = new JarInputStream(jin);
        ZipEntry ze2 = null;
        while ((ze2 = jin2.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            // this is bit of a hack to avoid stream closing,
            // since you can't get one for the inner entry
            // because you have no JarFile to get it from 
            FilterInputStream in = new FilterInputStream(jin2) {
                public void close() throws IOException {
                    // ignore the close
                }
            };

            // now you can process the input stream as needed
            JavaClass clazz = new ClassParser(in, "").parse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @WhiteFang34 your solution help me 80% so firstly thank you very much.Now 2ndly I DON'T want to create another file through FileOutputStream i need to have the InputStream of the jarEntry.hear in your code i need to get the inputStream of ze2.So help a bit more.

Comment: @zaree: no problem. In my example you want to use `jin2` as your `InputStream` for the inner `ze2` entry. I only wrote it to another file to show and test that it works.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 firstly you can't instantiate InputStream and let say if i do something like InputStream in=new FileInputStream(ze2.getName().toStreing()); then it is not taking and in case of taking the jin2 become FileInputStream instead of JarInputStream then this doesn't work b/c we need to open the jar file to get the innerjar entry that is a file so don't reach to the exact point!kindly update ur snip of code.

Comment: @zaree: I updated the code in my answer. That should be all you need to do.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 I have run your given code BUT once you have get control of InputJarStream and utilize it to get inner details of a .class file then next time on doing jin2.getNextEntry() will not let u get the next entry control BECAUSE your Stream has been closed. y this happen and what should i do i got this output:::::Inner Jar Class Names=TeacherClass.class  This is the exception i got (java.io.IOException: Stream closed)

Comment: @zaree: I see what you're saying now. That does make this a little more complicated since you're dealing with an inner jar entry. I updated the answer with a way around the close problem.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 to avoid this Exception in the while loop end,i put a line "jin2.closeEntry();" but this still will not work it sitll gave the IOException "that stream is closed" do u have any guess or idea ?

Comment: @zaree: you tried my updated example? If you create a `FilterInputStream` named `in` and then pass `in` to `ClassParser` it'll avoid the close exception. It's working for me with `ClassParser` now. If it's still giving you trouble you might want to just extract the inner jars to the file system and then read those directly.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 thank your really much your help make my day.tanks again

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I was looking for a way how to scan classes that are packaged in a JAR in an EAR. There is really not much information out there. Fortunately I found your answer after several hours.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the `InnerJar.jar` first, then extract the class files from it.