# How to access contents of a jar using resource path?

Tags: java, url, jar

My problem is the following:
I am trying to access a class file in a Jar.
I have a jar "dumb.jar" located in package "com.msgxsd". The jar is on the classpath, and If I try and do

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("com/msgxsd/dumb.jar");
```

then I get an input stream for the jar without a problem.

The problem arises when I try and get an input stream (or a URL) for the file inside the jar. All the jar contains (apart from the manifest obviously) is the file "DummyClass1.class".

I have tried all of the following:

`InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("DummyClass1.class");`

`InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("dumb.jar!/DummyClass1.class");`

But the input stream returned is always null. I have also tried

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("DummyClass1.class");
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("dumb.jar!/DummyClass1.class");
```

But the URL returned is null.

I have already looked at every single one of the questions relating to accessing a file within a Jar, but the proposed solutions (as seen above) do not work for me.

All I want is to be able to get either an InputStream (or ideally a URL) for the "DummyClass1.class" inside the jar, so that I can the somehow construct a File instance.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan He said the jar is in a package. it is bundled like a resource in a package

Comment: What is the objective of access the '.class' file in your jar?

Comment: @MarcusMathioudakis exactly what kind of object is `this`?

Comment: @maress i thought that even if the jar in a package , he has to import the class he wants to use in his class

Comment: this is just a unit test, residing in com/msgxsd, so same package as the jar.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I need to access the file so that I can construct a File instance and use it to reason about the code. I'm using reflection to initialize one of my classes, but unfortunately when I deploy my application jar, the class's static initializer fails due to the URI of a class contained in a jar not being hierarchical

Comment: If you're trying to access a *class* file, why are you asking for the *jar* file? It's not clear what you even mean by having a jar file within a package. Please give a short but *complete* example of what's going on.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can see why my having a jar within a package is confusing: Basically I'm trying to replicate the situation occurring in my deployed application, but within a unit test. The deployed application is a Jar, and one of the classes within that jar has a static initializer which examines the contents of another package, scanning it for class files. This works fine in my source distribution, as all the class files are in regular folders, and thus the urls that point to them are hierarchical. However in the deployed application, this is not the case, as app.jar is on each class file's path

Comment: @MarcusMathioudakis: It's still not clear enough for me to reproduce easily. As I said, a short but complete application (and the steps required to create the relevant jar files) would make all of this simpler to tackle.

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to leave my workstation now, so will no longer have access to my source code for today, but will return tomorrow morning and edit the question (and include code) to make it clearer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonSkeet I have asked a new, hopefully clearer question relating to what I am trying to do, If you would like take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (sorry if there are typos, I'm just typing the code off the top of my head without trying it):

```
int index = path.indexOf('!');
if (index == -1) return url.openStream();
String jarPath = path.substring(0, index);
File jarFile = new File(new URL(jarPath).toURI());

if (!jarFile.exists()) return null;

String filePath = path.substring(index + 1);
if (filePath.startsWith("/")) {
    filePath = filePath.substring(1);
}

JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
return jar.getInputStream(jar.getJarEntry(filePath));
```

Comment: Did you try with `url = new URL("file://com/msgxsd/dumb.jar!/DummyClass1.class");` ?

Comment: Many Thanks, I have got this working. Unfortunately it doesn't work if the resource in question is a directory instead of a regular file (as you can't create an InputStream for a JarEntry that points to a directory), but my question was for a regular file, so you have answered it :).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dumb.jar/DummyClass1.class");
```

maybe specify the DummyClass1.class location inside the jar

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/msgxsd/dumb.jar!/DummyClass1.class")
```

Comment: @MarcusMathioudakis: did you try removing the `/` after the `!` ?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use a `JarInputStream` to access the contents of the jar file directly. Then iterate through the `JarEntry` collection until you find the file you are looking for and read it from the stream. Something like this:

```
JarInputStream jarIn = new JarInputStream(this.getClass().getClassLoader() .getResourceAsStream("com/msgxsd/dumb.jar"));  
JarEntry entry = jarIn.getNextJarEntry();
```

Now read the file using the `jarIn` read method.

Comment: what if the jarEntry is a directory?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing for you to do is to move your jar so that it is included directly in the classpath, or change your classpath to also include "com/msgxsd" as a top-level entry.  In either of these cases `DummyClass` will be loaded by the standard `ClassLoader` and you can simply do `getResourceAsStream("DummyClass1.class")` as you have already suggested.

If changing your classpath in this way is not possible then you need to create a `JarInputStream` as suggested by @Micky above or in this [more complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788396/991432).